# How to extract and store a value from jmeter response and store inn csv?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

My Jmeter response looks like..

https://adcd.com/abc/bcd/mock.jsp?profile=teslatest&JTnumber=132323235674897&SUTest=27&SUName=Alexa&TARGET=abcd.com">

How to extract JTnumber from this and store in a csv?
How about if we have 20 different JTnumbers from 20 responses? How to save all in a csv??

Please help me in achieving this..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=JTnumber
   ```

   see [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) chapter of the JMeter User Manual for more information.
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response and configure it like:

   [image]
4. Add [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
5. That's it, when you run the test you will see `values.csv` file in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation containing all these `JTnumber` values, each on new line