# How to extract Cookie from Request Body of View Results Tree in JMeter ? I want to save them to CSV File to use in future

Tags: cookies, jmeter

In My application the login page is very slow such that when I perform load test its breaks even before going to the main page. For that with few login credentials and by iterating them I need to generate new cookie everytime and store all of them in .csv file so that in near future I can just use cookie to login and load test won't break.

Request Body has
**Cookie Data:
cb=k3fp7s1rnjoil48ep8aeilro64; lang=en_US**

Comment: If you add an example of what the Requests Body in the View Results Tree in JMeter looks like then we might be able to point you to a solution.

Comment: My request body has "Cookie Data:
cb=k3fp7s1rnjoil48ep8aeilro64; lang=en_US
"

Comment: Meghana Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635179/how-to-extract-and-store-a-value-from-jmeter-response-and-store-inn-csv

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next lines to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   sample_variables=COOKIE_cb
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the changes
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
4. Add [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
5. That's it, when you run your test next time you will see a new file called `values.csv` holding the cookies for each thread (virtual user), each cookie on the new line.

Comment: I have tried the above steps but it didn't work for me. Should I add Regular Expression Extractor in Test Plan?